# Search neglects quoted square-bracketed terms

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

If you search for something within square brackets, within quotes, the search seems to ignore the bracketed part. For example, [searching for `"[something] query"`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%5Bsomething%5D+query%22), seems to display results for just *" query"*, as shown below:

[image: bracketed search term gone missing]

Comment: Normally searching for `[something]` would only include results with the `something` tag (which is nothing, since that tag doesn't exist), but that probably shouldn't happen if the bracketed string is in quotes. In this case it does seem to just ignore the bracketed string completely; it doesn't show up in the right bar and doesn't filter the results correctly

Comment: Indeed, and I agree, I don't think that it should consider that a tag. I actually don't even mind too much if it intentionally ignores it because it *is* bracketed, so long as the UI makes that a bit more apparent.

Comment: I'd advocate the Google method -- searching "[thing] stuff" becomes "thing stuff".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an artifact of a tag cleanup parsing step that's no longer relevant (that I can think of, else I've broken *that* now).

Starting with the next build, that aggressive excess-tag stripper won't interfere here.