# How is my search query broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

To facilitate searching for questions which [might contain an appended answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103154), I plugged in (on Stack Overflow):

- `solved` which returns 5,000+ -- a bit too many to be useful.

So I refined it to:

- `[solved]` & `[Solved]` return nothing (as expected -- the tag doesn't exist)
- `"[solved]"` & `"[Solved]"` which return **nothing**??
- title:[solved] **wierd** -- see below
- title:"[solved]" which returns nothing

## Existence

Through all of this, note for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290134/vtune-no-symbols-available-solved) which *does* contains `[Solved]` in the title?

So upon investigating the `title:[solved]`, I see:

- [`title:[solved]` returns 1,518 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A[solved])
- [`title:[closed]` returns **the same** 1,518 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A[closed])
- [`title:[waffles]` returns **the same** 1,518 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A[waffles])
- [`title:[narwahls]` returns **the same** 1,518 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A[narwahls])
- [`title:[42]` returns **the same** 1,518 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A[42])
- [`title:[` returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A[)
- [`title:[]` returns nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A[])

**Question:** So what am I doing wrong?!?

Comment: Likely related: [Search neglects quoted square-bracketed terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102459)

Comment: I knew it didn't like "[<anything>]" in searches, but getting the same 1,518 results over and over is bizarre.  Good catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We had some code in there to strip any errant tags that was a bit too liberal in where it was applied.  Though we won't support `[string]` in the ninja options, *in the next build* we won't just strip your text...it will be parsed as `string`.

I'll look at parsing `[` and `]` as part of the normal parse, but it's not a simple matter and it's a complete analyzer (well, tokenizer really) switch on the back end (and needs a re-index).  I can't make any promises, but I'll try to improve the behavior here and see if we can treat some commonly used symbols are non-breaks or stops in the parsing.\

To be clear: what was happening before was your search ending up as `"title:"` in *every* case above...this is what will be resolved, the rest is a todo.txt item for me.