# Why doesn't searching "vim" or "vim]" automatically switch to questions tagged "vim"?

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-search

In the past (before the latest search system changes), typing `perl` in the search field would redirect me to all of the questions with the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) tag. Great. Even more great: this is still working.

If I try to reach the *C* questions instead, well it never worked. However, searching for `c]`  would work, and works.

Soon I realized it was related to the number of characters in a tag. And three characters used to work. But **used to** work. Not anymore.

Searching for *vim* won't go to its tag page. And the most impressive thing: searching for `vim]` won't work either.

So, what's up with the search system?

Comment: Actually, I like to be able to search for questions containing `vim`, independently if they are actually tagged [tag:vim].  This works for some words which also are tag names (github, jsch), but not for others (git, java redirect to the tag if used as the sole search word) - I guess it depends on the popularity of the related tag or the word usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to search any question containing "vim" you search for "[vim](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vim)"; if you want to look for any question tagged [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), you search for "[[vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim)]."

Maybe the search code was more permissive before, and if you entered *vim]* understood that you meant to write *[vim]*. The syntax for searching questions tagged with a tag has always been the same, and it is well documented; with "well documented" I mean that the documentation reports to enclose the tag between *[* and *]* and not, for example, to use at least one of *[* (at the beginning of the tag name) and *]* (at the end of the tag name).

Comment: I was actually about to edit the question because I thought `c]` was a typo for `[c]`!

Comment: I know I'd have to search for `[vim]`. And I didn't had to type `vim]`, only `vim` was enough. And yeah, I know it's well documented, but why removing such meaningful shortcut? I'd love to know what three-letter word was responsible for doing this, I doubt it's tag is not appropriate.

Comment: @Josh, indeed helpful, eh? When you want to open the C questions page what do you do? Go over to the mouse, or hit `<tab>c]<enter>`? :-P

Comment: If you use a non documented feature, the feature could not work anymore when they change code (it could be the "feature" was really a bug). Documented features should always work; if they don't work, or there is a bug, or the documentation was not exact. What I meant with _well documented_ is that there isn't confusion about what the documentation suggests on how to search questions tagged with a tag.

Comment: I think this may be partly my fault [for asking about "[such]" things](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103157/how-is-my-search-query-broken).

Comment: We redirect for the top n tags on single search words. See the search help page.